# Where do applications on a linux system get their font information?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, fonts, buildroot

I am trying to create a kiosk application with the GTK framework on a raspberry pi

I am also using the buildroot build system for creating the custom linux system.

My graphics stack inludes using the Xorg server as the backend to GTK and i have enabled mesa to provide the OpenGL apis for rendering

On launching the system, the application is rendered on a small part of the screen (even though it is supposed to be full screen)

Also no fonts are shown at all. Images (SVG) are also not loaded.
The only thing that is rendered correctly is the layout

I am assuming i have some issues with my fonts.

Do all applications on a linux system render their fonts from an independent font package ?

Comment: please do not ask a question like `do all xyz use abc123?` ... the answer will always be `no, not all` because there is always an exception to everything

Comment: This looks like a question for https://stackoverflow.com *Do all applications on a linux system render their fonts from an independent font package ?* this question doesn't make sense to me.